# Trigger change event in AdWords ideas tool search box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, google-ads-api

I need to generate ideas with adwords keywords planner tool from a big amount of seed keywords. This process would be quite cumbersome to do manually, therefore I tried to automate it simulating human interaction with the tool via the JavaScript console.

There is a textarea where to insert your seed keywords and a button to press.

I can change the text in the search box and I can trigger the 'find ideas' button. But somehow even if I change the text in the box via JavaScript, when I trigger the find button, the text in the box is reverted to the last manual input before it's sent.

I tried to trigger many event handlers (`keypress`, `change`, `keydown`, `keyup`) but nothing changed.

I suppose the text is saved in some variable when input manually, but can't understand why I can't simulate this process!

Any ideas?

Comment: This is going to be very difficult for someone to debug for you without access to the source code. Have you tried perusing through the JS source for the webpage?

Comment: it's not my code. It's google's :) and it's compressed, so not very helpful!